# pyspark find out of range values in a dataframe

Tags: python, pyspark

I have two dataframes in pyspark. I am trying to compare one dataframe with another to see if the values lies in range.

Below is an example of dataframe.

Dataframe df :

[image]

Dataframe dfcompare :

[image]

Output i am looking for :

[image]

Code I have currently is below :

```py
def cal_OTRC(spark_df):
  compare = df.compare.fillna(0)
  df = spark_df.agg(*(F.count(F.when((F.col(c) > compare.astype(int).values.tolist()[0]) | (F.col(c) < compare[c].astype(int).values.tolist()[1]), c)).alias(c)  for c in spark_df.columns ))
  return df

out_of_range_count = cal_OTRC(df).to_koalas().rename(index={0: 'outofRange'})
```

However this code works for small table but for big tables this is very slow. Any improvements which can be done to run this faster for big tables

Comment: Yes it is dfcompare. Basically trying to search the outliers data count based on the max and min values

Answer (score 0):

You could translate `dfcompare` into a dict with one `min` and `max` entry per column.

```python
compare = {'empid': {'min': 1, 'max': 3}, 'salary': {'min': 100, 'max': 400}}
```

Then a column expression can calculate per column if a value is out of the range

```python
df = <load data>
df = df.select("*", *[ F.when((F.col(c)< compare[c]['min']) | (F.col(c)>compare[c]['max']), 1) \
    .otherwise(0).alias("out_{}".format(c)) for c in compare])
```

This produces a `0` or `1` per row and column:

```
+-----+------+---------+----------+
|empid|salary|out_empid|out_salary|
+-----+------+---------+----------+
|    1|    50|        0|         1|
|    2|   600|        0|         1|
|    3|   300|        0|         0|
|    4|   400|        1|         0|
|    5|  1000|        1|         1|
+-----+------+---------+----------+
```

Finally summing over the `out` columns gives

```python
df = df.select( *[F.sum("out_{}".format(c)) for c in compare])
```

```
+--------------+---------------+
|sum(out_empid)|sum(out_salary)|
+--------------+---------------+
|             2|              3|
+--------------+---------------+
```

Comment: how to convert the psypark dataframe compare to dict. I am reading data from Hive databases into psypark dataframe. In this scenario how do I put it in dictonary to run through above solution.

Comment: @abhishekgaikwad what is the structure of the hive table?

Comment: It is not fixed has I am passing table in this logic has a parameter to get the out of range values for my table. So my table will be changing. Once i read any hive table to dataframe how do i convert that pyspark dataframe to dict.

Comment: @abhishekgaikwad you could check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49432167/2129801) and its various answers. It might or might not help you with the transformation. But without knowing the structure of the table its difficult to say how to transform it. It will certainly require some coding.